# remove class on mouseout jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseout

I'm using a jquery slide menu that works great!

I need to add a remove function on sub class when mouseout

code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /* position of the <li> that is currently shown */
            var current = 0;

            var loaded  = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i <5; ++i)
                $('<img />').load(function(){
                    ++loaded;
                    if(loaded == 4){
                        $('#bg1,#bg2,#bg3,#bg4').mouseover(function(e){

                            var $this = $(this);
                            /* if we hover the current one, then don't do anything */
                            if($this.parent().index() == current)
                                return;

                            /* item is bg1 or bg2 or bg3, depending where we are hovering */
                            var item = e.target.id;

                            /*
                            this is the sub menu overlay. Let's hide the current one
                            if we hover the first <li> or if we come from the last one,
                            then the overlay should move left -> right,
                            otherwise right->left
                             */
                            if(item == 'bg1' || current == 2)
                                $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-265px 0)"},300,function(){
                                    $(this).find('li').hide();
                                });
                            else
                                $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(198px 0)"},300,function(){
                                    $(this).find('li').hide();
                                });

                            if(item == 'bg1' || current == 2){
                                /* if we hover the first <li> or if we come from the last one, then the images should move left -> right */
                                $('#menu > li').animate({backgroundPosition:"(-760px 0)"},0).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').addClass(item);
                                move(1,item);
                            }
                            else{
                                /* if we hover the first <li> or if we come from the last one, then the images should move right -> left */
                                $('#menu > li').animate({backgroundPosition:"(760px 0)"},0).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').addClass(item);
                                move(0,item);
                            }

                            /*
                            We want that if we go from the first one to the last one (without hovering the middle one),
                            or from the last one to the first one, the middle menu's overlay should also slide, either
                            from left to right or right to left.
                             */
                            if(current == 2 && item == 'bg1'){
                                $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-266px 0)"},300);
                            }
                            if(current == 0 && item == 'bg4'){
                                $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+3)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(266px 0)"},300);
                            }


                            /* change the current element */
                            current = $this.parent().index();

                            /* let's make the overlay of the current one appear */

                            $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},300,function(){
                                $(this).find('li').fadeIn();
                            });
                        });
                    }   
                }).attr('src', 'images/'+i+'.jpg');


            /*
            dir:1 - move left->right
            dir:0 - move right->left
             */
            function move(dir,item){
                if(dir){
                    $('#bg1').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},200);
                    $('#bg2').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-190px 0)"},300);
                    $('#bg3').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-380px 0)"},400);
                    $('#bg4').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-570px 0)"},400,function(){

                        $('#menuWrapper').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').addClass(item);
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $('#bg1').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},400,function(){
                        $('#menuWrapper').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').addClass(item);
                    });
                    $('#bg2').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-190px 0)"},300);
                    $('#bg3').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-380px 0)"},200);
                    $('#bg4').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-570px 0)"},200);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Html below:

```
  <div id="content" style="float: right;"><div id="menuWrapper" class="menuWrapper bg1" style="height:188px!important;">

            <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                <li class="bg1" style="background-position:0 0;">
                    <a id="bg1" class="selected" href="#">menu1</a>
                    <ul class="sub1" style="background-position:-265px 0;">
                        <li></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-190px 0px;">
                    <a id="bg2" href="#">menu2</a>
                    <ul class="sub2" style="background-position:-265px 0;">
                        <li></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-380px 0px;">
                    <a id="bg3" href="link.htmlp">menu3</a>
                    <ul class="sub3" style="background-position:-265px 0;">
                        <li></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="last bg1" style="background-position:-570px 0px;">
                    <a id="bg4" href="#">menu4</a>
                    <ul class="sub4" style="background-position:-266px 0;">
                        <li></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery's [*hover()*](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), which uses the more appropriate *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* events.

Comment: could you please provide me code to add this function in this case?

Comment: I'm a newbie with jquery. Please help me with a code for this case